# Avoid type widening with implicit?

Tags: scala, implicit

Tried to avoid a specific literal type widening with an implicit class:

```scala
implicit class keepAsListOfInt(val listOfInt: List[Int]) extends AnyVal {
  def :+(long: Long): List[Int] = listOfInt :+ long.toInt
}

// Won't compile - already widened to List[AnyVal]
val listOfInt: List[Int] = List(1) :+ 2L
```

But since the compiler has already widened the expression `List(1) :+ 2L` to `List[AnyVal]` the implicit conversion is never called. Can I somehow enforce the conversion implicitly?

UPDATE - Thanks to [sachav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4623415/sachav)'s reply and [Alexey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9204/alexey-romanov)'s valid concerns, the following code seems to do the job:

```scala
import scala.language.implicitConversions

implicit def listAnyValToListInt(l: List[AnyVal]): List[Int] = l.map {
  case n: Int                      => n
  case n: Long if n < Int.MinValue =>
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't cast too small Long to Int: " + n)
  case n: Long if n > Int.MaxValue =>
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't cast too big Long to Int: " + n)
  case n: Long                     => n.toInt
  case v                           =>
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid value: " + v)
}

val valid: List[Int] = List(1) :+ 2
val invalid: List[Int] = List(1) :+ 30000000000L // fails at runtime
```

It would still be nice though if there was a compile-time solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ugly solution would be to accept the conversion to `List[AnyVal]`, and add an implicit conversion from `List[AnyVal]` to `List[Int]`:

```
implicit def listAnyValToListInt(l: List[AnyVal]): List[Int] = l.map {
  case e: Int => e
  case e: Long => e.toInt
}

val listOfInt: List[Int] = List(1) :+ 2L //compiles
```

Although an undesirable side-effect will be that an expression such as `val listOfInt: List[Int] = List(1) :+ 2.0` will throw a MatchError.

Comment: Another undesirable side-effect is that `List(1) :+ 30000000000L` compiles, and doesn't even throw anything.

Answer (score 1):

The applicable method `:+` is available on the `List` class itself, so the compiler doesn't bother looking up any other methods with the same name added by implicits.

I think the best solution may be [WartRemover](http://www.wartremover.org/), as it happens this case is covered by the built-in [`AnyVal` wart](http://www.wartremover.org/doc/warts.html).

Comment: Thanks, Alexey, but unfortunately my code has to run in a dynamically created ScalaFiddle where I won't be able to use the WarRemover plugin.